# file_get_contents not working?

Tags: php, regex, file-get-contents

This code is not working to server. But It is working to my localhost (xampp)

```
$url = file_get_contents('http://www.site.com/');
$xhtml='|<tr style="background-color:#dddddd;">
        <td class="odd" align="left">(.+?)</td><td class="odd">(.+?)</td>
    </tr>|i';
preg_match_all($xhtml,$url,$score);
array_shift($score);
echo"<pre>";
print_r($score);
echo"</pre>";
```

It prints another scores when I change the code like this. Because there are two  rows like this. It has same  codes. by the way below code works to server.

```
$xhtml='|<td class="odd" align="left">(.+?)</td><td class="odd">(.+?)</td>|i';
```

I need to take this two values between  code.

```
allow_url_fopen = on
```

Comment: Is "allow_url_fopen = On" in php.ini?

Comment: Yes. allow_url_fopen = on  First code works to localhost not to server, second code work both. But I need firt code. Because It provide true score.

Comment: Are you sure both php cli and php apache2 php.ini's are allowing `allow_url_fopen`?

Comment: in my case it was the chroot directive in php config that was causing the problem

Answer (score 28):

**Try this function in place of file_get_contents():**

```
<?php

function curl_get_contents($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
```

It can be used just like file_get_contents(), but uses cURL.

Install cURL on Ubuntu (or other unix-like operating system with aptitude):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

See also [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: My hosting provider Netfirms must have disallowed `file_get_contents()` but this function worked in it's place. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

You need to allow

```
 allow_url_fopen
```

in your php.ini config file. Some hosts disallow it for security

Answer (score 10):

I know this topic is old, but I had to figure this out on my own and figure it will help someone later.

Like the above says:

You need:

allow url fopen
allow url include

If you are using CURL then you need curl extension

If you are file_get_contents of a https:// I believe you also need apache ssl module, as well as openssl php extension.

Without OpenSSL and SSL Module doing a file_get_contents on a facebook graph (obviously https://) it returned "No file found" error.

Comment: I had the same problem. file_get_contents on https: -> facebook graph API -> returning false. CURL solved this problem.

Comment: I was having https issue... I think that you should make it bold in your answer to highlight it.

Answer (score 3):

Also check whether you have: **allow_url_include On**

And make sure that there are no network permission issues like **403 Forbidden**.

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue and it turned out to be something unusual.  We were trying to file_get_contents('https://www.google.com');  the issue for us was because the server was set to use ipv6 but it had no ipv6 ip assigned.  We disabled ipv6 and had it use ipv4 and it worked.  Just another thing on the list to check.

Answer (score 0):

If `allow_url_fopen` is `On` then disable your ***firewall*** or ***csf*** and check again.