# PHP 'file_get_contents' does not work from server

Tags: php, cross-domain

I have a `website` (PHP) hosted in Yahoo small business and `application` (Java) Hosted in Rackspace.

I am making a `file_get_contents` from website to application. which works fine in my local. but when i try the same after deploying it in server does not work.

Here i am making arequest which sends list of training in `JSON` format.

**PHP part**

```
  $trainingArrayJson = file_get_contents('http://mywebapplication.com/publicTraining/getTrainingsAsJson/');
 $trainingArray =  json_decode($trainingArrayJson);
      -------
      -----
```

this is not working.

if i do

```
   $trainingArrayJson = file_get_contents('http://localhost:8080/publicTraining/getTrainingsAsJson/');
 $trainingArray =  json_decode($trainingArrayJson);
```

this works fine.

Comment: Refer the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794604/file-get-contents-not-working

Answer (score 4):

You need to allow

```
allow_url_fopen
```

in your php.ini config file. Some hosts disallow it for security.

Answer (score 1):

A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled. See fopen() for more details on how to specify the filename. See the Supported Protocols and Wrappers for links to information about what abilities the various wrappers have, notes on their usage, and information on any predefined variables they may provide.

Comment: Go this page and you will many different combinations, this may help you, http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

Check the php.ini file and make sure similar is available as below

; Whether to allow the treatment of URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as files.
; http://php.net/allow-url-fopen
allow_url_fopen = On

; Whether to allow include/require to open URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as files.
; http://php.net/allow-url-include
allow_url_include = Off