# How to get POST data by using CURL?

Tags: php, security, curl, post, file-get-contents

I want to turn OFF `allow_url_fopen` for security reasons. If I turn it off, I cannot use `file_get_contents`.

I'm using `file_get_contents` with `php://input` and URL. as I need to get the POST data with it. Something like this:

```
$postData = file_get_contents('php://input'); // Example 1
$postData2 = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', false, $context); // Example 2
```

Is there any way I can get the POST data by using CURL or any other secure way?

Comment: using cURL for reading your incoming POST data makes no sense - that's for making outgoing HTTP requests to a remote server. It has nothing to do with the request that PHP is currently responding to. I'm assuming maybe you can't just use $_POST to get the data? Perhaps you have JSON coming in or something instead of form data?

Comment: @ADyson sorry im new to this. Im trying to get the POST data from Stripe webhook - https://gist.github.com/boucher/1708172

Comment: If you're running the code in that Git page, then yes it looks like you've got JSON coming in. Not sure you've got much option here, you need `php://input` I'm afraid, at least as far as I'm aware there's no workaround in that scenario.

Comment: @ADyson Darn it. does that mean users can pass malicious files with it like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049534/is-allow-url-fopen-safe

Comment: Only if you use file_get_contents() elsewhere in your code in a way that's unsafe (e.g. you make a call to file_get_contents where the URL (or some part of it) is taken from user input which you haven't checked and sanitised beforehand. Using it just for reading from `php://input` is not, in itself, unsafe. And using it to fetch the content of hard-coded URLs or filenames (or if not hard-coded, taken from somewhere where outside input cannot be incorporated into it) is not unsafe either by itself.