# file_get_contents Not Work If Value is Gained from Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to read other sites on my web with `file_get_contents()`. My value can be with javascript merging.

My site page is : `http://example.com/page.html#2010/09/awesome.html`

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
// results: 2010/09/awesome.html
```

**PHP**

```
$hash = "<script>document.write(hash);</script>";
$resultLink = "http://www.external-site.com/" .$hash;
$content = file_get_contents($resultLink);
$first_step = explode("<div class='post-entry'>" , $content );
$second_step = explode("</div>" , $first_step[1] );

echo $second_step[0];
```

Here **$resultLink** is : `http://www.external-site.com/2010/09/awesome.html`
But `file_get_contents($resultLink)` can not open the page.

How can I fix this code?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794604/file-get-contents-not-working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file\_get\_contents not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794604/file-get-contents-not-working)

Comment: What errors are you receiving?

Comment: @Enstage Content on external-site can not be opened with `file_get_contents`

Comment: I suspect you're trying to execute JS in PHP / PHP in JS, which is not how it works. JS is executed client side (in the user's browser), PHP is server side.

Comment: @EnstageYes, then how the correct code for that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is JS is executed client side, which is AFTER the PHP is executed and produces content to send to the browser.

For example, by doing what you're doing `$resultLink` contains `http://www.external-site.com/<script>document.write(hash);</script>`

Comment: i do not know. but the **echo $resultLink** is `http://www.external-site.com/2010/09/awesome.html`

Comment: You are right. It turns on the `view-source:` the result is another :)