# File_get_contents and Telegram API (reply_markup)

Tags: php, api, telegram

i want to make a command that send a message with button like this

[image: open me plz]

So i did this

```
$url = "https://api.telegram.org/" . $token . "/sendMessage?chat_id=" . $message_chat_id . "&text=" . urlencode($message_text) . '&reply_markup={"inline_keyboard":[[{"text":"Visualizza spoiler!","url":"http://google.com/"}]]}';
```

and it make this url

```
https://api.telegram.org/censored/sendMessage?chat_id=censored&text=%2Fspoiler+ciao&reply_markup={"inline_keyboard":[[{"text":"Visualizza spoiler!","url":"http://google.com/"}]]}
```

when i use this url in browser it works but when i use file_get_contents it doesn't

someone can help me?

Comment: Did you try with CURL? What version of PHP is that? Did you check if file_get_contents is enabled on server?

Comment: nop, because until now i used file_get_contents;
php5.6; yes it is enabled because if i want to send a simple message it works

Comment: Can you try with simple curl? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794604/file-get-contents-not-working

Comment: Now it works, i love you man, do u know why with file_get_contents didn't it work?

Comment: I don't really know to be honest but I had the same problem with another host some days ago. CURL then worked. I'll add an answer.

Comment: Your host may be unable to reach telegram servers in some countries (e.g. Russia) while your browser may be able to, if you're browsing from another contry, or, say, via VPN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem few days ago and I just tried CURL instead and it worked.

```
function curl_get_contents($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```